# Project sun path onto Google maps for given observer position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, coordinates, astronomy

I have the following list of details

```
Latitude and Longitude,
Date/Time
Altitude and Azimuth
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate a relative latitude and longitude to the one used in my calculation so I can draw an oval with Google Maps V3 (JavaScript)

Is this possible or should I convert my lat/lng to page pixels and do it that way (but this isn't how I want to achieve the task)

[EDIT]

I'm trying to gather latitude and longitude coordinates based on the altitude and azimuth as viewed by a single observer, so one single point on my map I want to visualise the path of the sun throughout the day/time.

Comment: What is a "relative" latitude and longitude?

Comment: "Relative" to the observer. Something of an arc/circle around my current latitude and longitude.

Comment: So you are trying to drop a circle on a map around each of the coordinates in your list? Or around your current location?

Comment: On a single set of coordinates (lat/long) on my map to show the current suns position/path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: after chatting with Dave, I believe the following method will yield an accurate projection of a sun position onto a map.

Here's a quick sketch of what the projection looks like. It's (supposed to be) 3D. We want to project the sun down onto a 2D surface where x and y are our offsets for the observer, and z is the distance to the projected sun:

[image: sun projection diagram]

Known:

- distance from earth to sun, S = 149,597,870,700 m
- phi (sun azimuth)
- theta (sun altitude)

What we really want is z (distance) and phi, the bearing. phi is known, so we need z. Keep in mind that S is gigantic so we should scale it down to a smaller number so our coordinates can be seen on the map. As long as we keep our new S constant, this shouldn't matter. Now, to find z:

```
sin(theta) = z / S, therefore z = S * sin(theta)
```

Once we have distance z and bearing phi, we can use these equations from [movable-type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate a lat/lng coordinate:

```
var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
          Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );

var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                 Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

where `d = distance traveled = our z` and `R = earth's radius = 6371000 (meters)`

That was easy! Now just iterate over all your sun positions and draw them on the map.

Here are some quick results, using S=1000:

```
Azimuth    altitude    z
110        5           87
150        20          342
180        70          939
210        20          342
```

Note that if you're dealing with very large distances this will not be entirely accurate due to the difficulties of modeling the Earth.

Comment: I'm trying to gather latitude and longitude coordinates based on the altitude and azimuth as viewed by a single observer, so one single point on my map I want to visualise the path of the sun throughout the day/time.

Comment: I think I understand. I think you can still use the above method. For each azim/alt, determine how far out you want the sun marker to appear (for d) and then your azimuth = bearing.

Comment: I'll start implementing this now, thanks. I'll report back, is there any articles you can reference for this calculation at all so I could further read up on it.

Comment: Just the site I linked. It has tons of resources for this sort of thing. I actually did something similar awhile back. Confusing, but possible. Good luck!

Comment: Sudden thought (and duh! moment) I don't have a distance, I have a single static point that doesn't change. Am I missing something?

Comment: You want to display the sun as a marker (or something) on the map, correct? I'm guessing you're trying to display a sun path as an envelope on the map. So you need a distance for how far away you want the sun marker to be from your marker.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27241/discussion-between-cianan-sims-and-dave-mackintosh)